# @bind-Value - ValueChanged.InvokeAsync overrides/refreshes other parameters

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

So I have a requirement that the component (called LookupBox) I am writing for a form has both a `Value`, defined as a Guid and a `DisplayValue` string, there would be two inputs on the form, one hidden (the Guid `Value`) and the other the text `DisplayValue` that would be visible.

The problem I am having though is I can bind the `Value` field but I can't also bind the `DisplayValue` field, so when `ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value)` is called the `DisplayValue` gets set to whatever it was when initialised.

```
<LookupBox Name="Customer" DisplayValue="@DisplayValue" @bind-Value="customer.Id"></LookupBox>
```

This LookupBox component has a method 'SetValue':

```
public async Task SetValue(Guid value, string displayValue) {
    this.Value = value;
    this.DisplayValue = displayValue;
    
    await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
        
    if (base.FieldIdentifier.FieldName != null) {
        EditContext editContext = base.EditContext;
        if (editContext != null) {
            FieldIdentifier fieldIdentifier = base.FieldIdentifier;
            editContext.NotifyFieldChanged(in fieldIdentifier);
        }
    }
    await base.Change.InvokeAsync(Value);            
}
```

If I try to `bind-` both parameters then whatever `~Changed.InvokeAsync` I call first works and the 2nd value is set back to the original.

Is there any way to bind multiple parameters so that both can be updated simultaneously? The `DisplayValue` does not need to be two bound both ways, it's just a human readable label.

The only alternative I can think of is making the bound value its own object with two values for Value and Display value.

Thanks.

Comment: This looks awfully like a version of select box.  What's the relationship between the `Guid` and the `DisplayValue`?  If you only show (and therefore can update) the `DisplayValue` how does the Guid get updated? What type of field is DisplayValue?  What does `LookupBox` look like?

Comment: You have to use One Property for Display and ID, like Dictionary. in this case you can control the relation between id and display, and you can set value by id that are exist on dictionary.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis So the LookupBox is essentially to display a foreign key, so imagine a relationship between an Order table and a Customer table, where Order has a CustomerId FK. The LookupBox is essentially a text input with a search button next to it, you click the button, it opens a Customer datagrid with search/filters, you select your Customer and the LookupBox is updated with the CustomerId (hidden) and Customer name (visible). It is to avoid the user seeing an unsightly Guid on the form, they get something that makes sense.

Comment: OK, I'll throw an answer together for you tomorrow (unless someone else answers first) :-)

Comment: Quick question.  Why are you trying to bind to both values?  If it's a FK field then the data model will only have the ID field, so you only need bind your control back to the data model Id field.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis So the way it works currently the LookupBox component is responsible for launching the 'lookup window' i.e. the datagrid from which to choose a value, that is then returned to the LookupBox. So there's not an elegant way that I can see that can separate out the text field and the guid id field.